# Electric current density when electric charge density is null?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics

I was reviewing electrodynamics then some minor detail caught my attention. In the notes I am reading (David Tong's), it has electric charge density $\rho=0$ but at the same time it assumes a steady current density $\mathbf{J}$. Certainly I could imagine a positive and negative charge moving together but then according to the definition of current density $\mathbf{J}=\rho\mathbf{v}$ isnt there a contradiction or sth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine a solid material with free electrons and an electric field across it. As you know, this, let's say a metallic rod, is neutral in charge. "positive" charges won't move/be affected and electrons on the other hand will. In your statement, the term $\rho$ is probably referring to density of the charges that can move. All the terms mentioned are to be viewed at in their classical meaning ofc.